# Do you sleep with your back "TO someone" or "AT someone"?

Tags: prepositions

If your back faces someone while you are sleeping, are you sleeping with your back "at them" or "to them"? Example: "She slept with her back AT him" OR "She slept with her back TO him"

Comment: What do you think the answer is? Have you done any research you can tell us about?

Comment: ***to*** is a common preposition for your context. But ***toward/towards, against*** are also fine (as is ***facing***, but I doubt that counts as a "preposition").

Comment: English prepositions are complicated and have lots of overlaps, and checking dictionary meanings is typically unhelpful for the "core" 10 or so most common English prepositions.  I don't find this a bad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO is correct. You can get a sense of this from [Google n-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with+my+back+to%2Cwith+her+back+to%2Cwith+his+back+to%2Cwith+my+back+at%2Cwith+her+back+at%2Cwith+his+back+at&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwith%20my%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20her%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20his%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20my%20back%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20her%20back%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20his%20back%20at%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwith%20my%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20her%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20his%20back%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20my%20back%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20her%20back%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20his%20back%20at%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: It's just the same whether you are standing, sitting, dancing or whatever with your back to someone.

Comment: It would be great if you could tell whether the following sentence (from a short story) is correct: "He looked at his sister who slept with her back to him." I wanted to know whether "to" is fine here or whether it should be "at".

Answer (score 0):

*X to Y* has a lot of meanings and one of those is a destination or direction identifier - it's used to express the target/direction that X is pointing or facing.

*X at Y* answers the question *where is X?* and this typically works in English only if Y is a place or a point on some type of line, sequence, or continuum.  This concept is usually invalid for a person's back unless the question *where?* is involved, implied, or identified as a concern for the speaker - e.g. "My hands are at her back".